# Are edge-triggered interrupts "hardware polled"?

Tags: cpu

Thanks in advance for assistance and patience with my hardware naivety

Reading the below answer about the NMI on pin 6 for an Apple 6502, and the signal on the pin falls from high to low, how does this get recognized by the edge detector to CPU food chain?  Is there "hardware polling" (each cycle check/read a bit, check a line, etc.) somewhere in the food chain?  Or is the change in voltage/signal a "triggering" or "notification" mechanism that obviates the need for "hardware polling" (no checking each cycle) in the food chain?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/57103/161733

My naive sense is the level-triggered interrupts are more analogous to "hardware polling".

But is the bottom line that the CPU (or some other hardware in the food chain) has to "hardware poll" the output from the edge or level or interrupt controllers at some point in each cycle? That the interrupt classification (edge-triggered, level-triggered) does not obviate the need for the CPU or interrupt handling food chain to "hardware poll" each cyle?

N.B. The above context is "input". When I say "hardware polling" I am not meaning a situation where the CPU is checking an external device to see if it is ready for more output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Saw on a different source that edge triggered interrupts set a latch inside the CPU. If I am reading it correctly, and I am oversimplifying, there is an AND gate that is checked by the CPU at beginning of each cycle with an input reflecting whether the last instruction finished, and a separate input reflecting whether there is a signal on an interrupt wire.

Comment: The CPU has internal hardware resources to monitor the external pins (in parallel) and change its behavior accordingly on every clock cycle. I would not call that polling.

Comment: @yves-daoust. Thank you. So every cycle the CPU checks for interrupts.

Comment: I would not say "checks". This is the normal handling of all external signals.

Comment: @yves-daoust Thank you for the clarification. How would you describe that monitoring or normal handling? is the AND gate example I gave in the prior comment in the neighborhood of being correct or did it miss the mark? is the CPU evaluating some flag, bit or gate that is has onboard? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by evaluating ?

Comment: I am probably using the wrong language. In the example above, assessing the Truth of the AND gate.

Comment: what is counted as "hardware polling"? everything in the CPU works on clock cycles - does that mean everything is hardware polled? like the register eax?

Comment: @user253751 Got it. Good point about the terminology. Thanks

Comment: @user253751 fetch-execute cycle would probably be more appropriate terminology than "hardware polling" :-). Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NMI pin on the 6502 isn't *exactly* edge-triggered. Rather, it is sampled into a latch on every cycle, and if the NMI line is asserted, the signal is held until the CPU is ready to service it.

And now, the long answer.

The 6502 timing uses a two-phase clock. The input clock signal (called $\phi_0$) is cleaned up and inverted to generate a clean two-phase clock signal (called $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$). The two clock pulses are never high at the same time, so during a clock cycle, the CPU can be said to be "in phase 1" and "in phase 2".

The [6502 hardware manual](http://bytecollector.com/archive/misc/6500-10A_MCS6500hwMan_Jan76.pdf) explains this.

[image: 6502 two-phase clock timing]

Given this clock design, you can implement a clock-edge-triggered latch in the usual way by using two level-triggered latches: one triggered by high level feeds into another triggered by low level.

(Note: In 1976, this was called a "master-slave" design. We don't use that terminology any more for obvious reasons, but also, as we are about to see, it's not always as simple as that.)

It's a little more complex in a CPU such as the 6502, because you can't half-execute an instruction. So an NMI signal may need to be stored for a few cycles.

In 1989, Donald Hanson did a detailed analysis of the 6502, citation at the end. In that paper, he came up with a detailed block diagram. According to this analysis, the interrupt delivery circuitry contains seven flip-flops, three of which handle NMI specifically. These are labelled NMIG, NMIL, and NMIP in the diagram.

[image: 6502 block diagram]

The other interesting part of the diagram are the timing logic latches, which generate signals for multi-cycle instructions. The CPU starts in state T0 at the start of an instruction, and transitions through various states up to T6, with the length of the sequence depending on the instruction.

So what happens when the external NMI signal is asserted is that a two-stage latch holds this signal until the NMI is ready to be serviced. NMI delivery doesn't commence until three conditions are met:

- The CPU is in the T0 state (i.e. no instruction is being executed).
- There isn't a RESET sequence in progress.
- The clock cycle is in phase 2.

One final point: NMI and IRQ do the same thing on a circuit level in the 6502. The main differences are:

- Priority. NMI takes priority over IRQ.
- IRQ can be masked.
- They go to different addresses.

Source:

Hanson, Donald F., *A VHDL Model for Pass Transistors Used in the 6502 Microprocessor*, Proceedings of the Fall 1989 VHDL Users' Group Meeting, Redondo Beach, CA, October 22-25, 1989, pp. 12-19 to 12-25.

**And having said all that...**

...interrupts on a modern computer work *very* differently than they did in the 1970s. When you have multiple cores, the operating system would like to control which core receives which interrupts. So today, this is all handled with message-passing between cores and external programmable I/O controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the above.

Comment: It has to be done with some kind of latch because otherwise there's a danger the interrupt edge could arrive too close to the clock edge, and the CPU wouldn't decide whether to do the interrupt or not before the clock edge.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for the additional input!  I work much higher in the stack (software guy) but I am trying to get my mental model refined on interrupts. The engineering is amazing. Peace

Comment: @user253751 Section 1.4.1.2.9 of the hardware manual linked above: "The /NMI signal must be low for at least two clock cycles for the interrupt to be recognized, whereupon new program count vectors are fetched."